# Herramienta para animación Angular

Tags: css, asp.net-core

Buen día chicos, quisiera crear una página web con Angular y Asp.net Core.
Además quiero implementar muchas animaciones, efectos o como lo quieran llamar pero no sé que usar, para que pueda hacerlo y que me vaya fluido la página.

Espero me pueda orientar un poco, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Motivo de cierre de la pregunta: _La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías de software u otros recursos externos_.

Comment: Considera que llevas 3 preguntas bajo prácticamente la misma temática, considera leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. En ninguno de los casos has agregado que has intentado y que dudas puntuales tienes, teniendo lo anterior presente es seguro te cierren las publicaciones